# Way to configure VS remote debugger via cmd

Tags: remote-debugging

I want to deploy `Visual Studio Remote Debugger` to the target machines automatically. I can install Remote Debugger silently via cmd, [grant required prevelegues to user](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/how-can-i-grant-user-rights-command-line) and [modify firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804753(v=surface.10).aspx). I have to configure it using `Wizard` (rdbgwiz.exe) and it seems the `Wizard` doesn't have command line parameters. How I can configure `Remote Debugger`? Is there a way to do it without the `Wizard`? What `Wizard` does? Just only creates a service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not neccesary to run `Wizard`. You could do the following:
1) Disable Windows Firewall completely. Unfortunately, partially fix as allowing connections for required ports doesn't work.
2) Install debugger, use **/q** option to silent install
3) Allow your account to `Log on as a Service`.
4) Change log on credentials for Remote Debugger service.
5) Enable debugger service.
6) Run it. *
So, my bat file looks like

```
@echo off

pushd %~dp0

netsh advfirewall set domain state off
netsh advfirewall set private state off
netsh advfirewall set public state off

if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (
  set arch=x86
) else (
  set arch=x64
)

"rtools_setup_%arch%.exe" /q

ntrights.exe -u %username% +r SeServiceLogonRight

sc config msvsmon120  obj= "%computername%\%username%" password= "password"
sc config msvsmon120 start= auto
sc start msvsmon120
```

*) Be careful about debugger version. Different versions of debugger have different service names: `msvsmon100` is for VS 2010 debugger, `msvsmon110` for 2012 and `msvsmon120` for 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this script for installing VS 2013 Remote Tools on my virtual dev environment using VirtualBox, Vagrant, Chocolatey and PowerShell. You could pick the bits you like if you don't use all of those tools.

```
Import-Module "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1"

# use different name for different versions
$VSMonitor = "msvsmon120"

Write-Host "Disabling firewall on host."
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile * -Enabled False

if ((get-service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $VSMonitor}) -eq $null) {

    # The shared /vagrant folder is not always properly mounted by Vagrant\Virtualbox or is still in the 
    # process doing so. To circumvent this we apply a net use on the shared /vagrant folder. This will make the 
    # c:\vagrant folder and the iso folder is accessible.   
    If(Test-Path "x:") {
        Write-Host "Removing network drive x:"
        net use x: /delete
    }

    Write-Host "Applying fix for shared c:\vagrant folder mounting problem by doing a net use x: on \\vboxsvr\vagrant"
    net use x: \\vboxsvr\vagrant

    Write-Host "Installing Visual Studio 2013 Remote Tools as it is not already installed."

    $installer = "c:\vagrant\iso\vs2013_with_update_4_rtools_setup_x64.exe"       
    $installerArgs = "/install /quiet"

    Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin -statements $installerArgs -exeToRun $installer -Wait

    Set-Service -Name $VSMonitor -StartupType "Automatic"

    Start-Service -Name $VSMonitor
} else {
    Write-Host "Not installing Visual Studio 2013 Remote Tools as it is already installed."
}
```